# Why my material look transparent, my normal are correct

Tags: rendering, mesh, materials, shaders, normals

trying to learn blender, I tried to apply some material from a texture to my low poly car.

[image: nor]

when I export this as glb the wheel looks like transparent, as you can see from the bottom screen.

[image: pic2]

Any reason ? Why this happened ? I check the normal and look like all with the correct orientation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have inverted normals, to fix that:

1. Select your wheel and enter Edit Mode by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals outside

Comment: i edit the question, but as you can see the normal are all facing in the correct direction.. but problem persist..

Comment: please share your blend file at https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Thanks a lot, I update the blender file and delated the other post.. Apologize..

Comment: Ah your scale is negative for the wheels. Make the scale positive and scale it a bit larger because it is also too small then press `Ctrl`+`A` *> Apply Scale*

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Adding to that.. If you apply scale you will see that the normals gets inverted.